# In XQuery, how to evaluate xpath from a string?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have an `XQuery` script that I would like to evaluate as I import new documents into a database. I want to evaluate an `Xpath` expression, with a predicate, from a string, and use the result to choose the appropriate collection.

It works perfectly if all of the code is in the `XQuery` file. I want to make it more dynamic than that and read `XPath` **expressions -> collection mappings dynamically**. Then, in each document, when an `XPath` expression returns a node, I have found the correct collection.

Is this possible? The `xdmp:unpath()` function isn't adequate. It doesn't support predicates.  `xdmp:eval()` and `xdmp:value()` seem to work but I can't get them to work only against a single document. Either that, or they just start to fail (returning true for any `XPath` expression) after 500 or so documents.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
(: Get XML from MarkLogic Record Loader. :)
let $doc := xdmp:unquote($XML-STRING, $UNQ-NAMESPACE, $UNQ-OPTIONS)

(: Get XPath expression from database. :)
let $xpath := doc("/mappings.xml")/mappings/rule/xpath

(: Evaluate. :)
let $result := some-function($doc, $xpath) 

(: Use the result.
return
    if(fn:count($result) > 0)
        ( $collection )
    else
        ()
```

Is there some construct that will make "some-function($doc, $xpath)" work?

It seems that in `XQuery`, `XPath` expressions are part of the syntax and can't be replaced by strings. I'm used to other languages like Perl where `XPath` is always a string and something like this would be trivial.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to elaborate more on what you tried using `xdmp:eval()` and `xdmp:value()`. I would expect that you could simply do `let $result := xdmp:value(concat($doc, $xpath))` and it would work.

Comment: Try thinking of XPath in XQuery like regex in Perl. Metaprogramming with regex in Perl is possible, but the techniques can be non-obvious. Metaprogramming with XPath in XQuery is similar.

Comment: xdmp:value was one of the first solutions I attempted. See below for more analysis. I am doing this in a record loader and things just aren't working the way they should.

Comment: I tried it one last time with that specific expression "xdmp:value(concat($doc, $xpath))" and it did work correctly. But I'm still sticking to the XSL solution for other reasons detailed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also rewrite your XML configuration file as XSLT, then evaluate it with `xdmp:xslt-invoke`. It would still be XML, just formatted a little differently. Each rule would be a template `match`, returning an `xsl:text` result with the collection name.

Comment: This is by far the best solution. I've always been an XSLT fan but hadn't used it in MarkLogic yet. See below for some analysis on the alternatives that strangely don't even return correct results.

Answer (score 1):

The right tool for this is `xdmp:value`. You might be having some trouble with the syntax, though. I'd use this:

```
xdmp:value(concat('$doc', $xpath))
```

That constructs an expression relative to $doc, something like `$doc/a/b/c`. Then we can evaluate that expression in the current context, where `$doc` is already defined.

```
let $doc := xdmp:unquote('<x>some xml <i>from somewhere</i></x>')
let $xpath := '/x/i'
return xdmp:value(concat('$doc', $xpath))
=>

<i>from somewhere</i>
```

Note that `xdmp:unquote` produces a document-node, so the first step is the `x` root element.

You can encapsulate this in your own function, and then you'll have `some-function($doc, $xpath)` working.

```
declare function local:my-unpath($doc as node(), $xpath as xs:string)
as item()*
{
  xdmp:value(concat('$doc', $xpath))
};

let $doc := xdmp:unquote('<x>some xml <i>from somewhere</i></x>')
let $xpath := '/x/i[starts-with(., "from")]'
return local:my-unpath($doc, $xpath)
```

Comment: I tried it one last time with this specific code and it worked. However, I am going to stick with the XSLT solution. I tried other constructs very similar to this with very strange results. If you remove the single quotes, it fails. If you try to use $doc/$xpath, it seems to match against the entire database instead of the specified document. I prefer an elegant solution with one, obvious expression to a solution with one correct, non-obvious expression and other, similar expressions the return incorrect results.

Comment: And in the process of debugging, the XSLT solution has equivalent performance to the xdmp:value() solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for [xdmp:unpath()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unpath).

Comment: It sounds like he has complex predicates. For example `xdmp:unpath('$doc/x/i[starts-with(., "from")]')` would throw `XDMP-UNPATH`, but works with `xdmp:value`. At the same time I wouldn't use `xdmp:eval`: overkill for this use case.